# Compass Style - Sprite: flexible background-image

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

i try to use the great Sprite feature of Compass for a simple tooltip.

The thing i want to create is:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/851/tooltipquestion.png/]

The html Code:

```
 <h2>*BUG* Sprite Tooltip with Compass</h2><br /><br />
        <div id="tooltip_test">
            <div class="tooltip-Tooltip_up"></div>
            <div class="tooltip-Tooltip_bg">asdsad<br /></div>
            <div class="tooltip-Tooltip_down"></div>
        </div>
        <h2>Sprite Tooltip with Compass &customBG</h2><br /><br />
        <div id="tooltip_test">
            <div class="tooltip-Tooltip_up"></div>
            <div class="custombg">asdsad</div>
            <div class="tooltip-Tooltip_down"></div>
        </div>
```

For the first tooltip, I use the bg class generated by compass.

For the second tooltip, I use a custom bg class (for showing you what I want)

The generated sprite is:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/tooltipsa3255cfa43.png/]

(the first pixel line is the background-image, then the header and footer)

So my question is:

**Is there a posibilty to repeat the bg-area of the spriteimage (generated by compass) in order to have a flexible height of the tooltip?**

The code of my manually generated class is:

```
 .custombg {
        background: url('images/tooltip/Tooltip_bg.png');
        height: 100px;
        width: 258px;
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A CSS-only solution: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#talkbubble

Comment: Thanks for the css-only link :)
But i really would like to use the sprite thing because of the IE support

Answer (score 0):

As of Compass v0.12, repeating a part of the sprite is possible, but repeat only works on the x-axis.

Because the middle part of your quote bubble is just a flat color you can style it with css and use your existing sprite for the top and bottom portions of the quote bubble.

There are many ways to do this using pure css3, however if you want to use the images to have this work in older versions of IE, you can use before and after pseudo-elements on a single html element.

Try this…

Using this file structure:

```
images/
  tooltip/
    top.png
    bottom.png
  tooltip-sfc34d436c9.png  <-- Sass will create this file.
sass/
  sprite.sass
sprite.html
stylesheets/
  sprite.css
```

And `sprite.html` contains this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="stylesheets/sprite.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tooltip">
      To be, or not to be, that is the question.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And `sprite.sass` contains this:

```
// Sprite setup
$tooltip-sprite-dimensions: true
@import "tooltip/*.png"

// Tooltip styles
$tooltip-top-image: "tooltip/top.png"
$tooltip-top-width: image-width($tooltip-top-image)
$tooltip-top-height: image-height($tooltip-top-image)
$tooltip-bottom-image: "tooltip/bottom.png"
$tooltip-bottom-width: image-width($tooltip-bottom-image)
$tooltip-bottom-height: image-height($tooltip-bottom-image)
$tooltip-width: $tooltip-top-width
$tooltip-h-padding: 10px
.tooltip
  position: relative
  width: $tooltip-width - ($tooltip-h-padding * 2)
  background: #8aa5bb
  padding: $tooltip-top-height $tooltip-h-padding $tooltip-bottom-height
  &:before
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    +tooltip-sprite(top)
  &:after
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    bottom: 0
    left: ($tooltip-width - $tooltip-bottom-width)/2
    +tooltip-sprite(bottom)
```

And `sprite.css` compiles to this `sprite.css`:

```
.tooltip-sprite, .tooltip:before, .tooltip:after {
  background: url('../images/tooltip-sfc34d436c9.png') no-repeat;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  width: 232px;
  background: #8aa5bb;
  padding: 15px 10px 13px;
}
.tooltip:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-position: 0 -13px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 252px;
}
.tooltip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -3px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 13px;
  width: 258px;
}
```

The finished tooltip will look like this:

[image: finished tooltip]